# Training Multi-Layer Perceptron correctly for powers of 2

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

I'm quite new to neural networks world, I followed some tutorials and was able to implement a MLP, but the activation function is a hyperbolic tangent, whose range is [-1:1].

I wrote a training file like this: `1 2 3 4 ... n`

and the target-output file is the powers of 2: `2 4 8 16 ... 2^n`

and I want the network to simulate this function, but I don't know how to adjust the **learning rate**, **momentum** and **activation function** in order to correctly simulate.

I tried the activation function `f(x) = x` (with derivative 1) to overcome the range problem (outputs between -1 and 1), but my output and error grew very fast with it, even when I decreased the learning rate, so I'm confused about how to modify these parameters in order to simulate `f(x) = 2^x` or how to train the net correctly.

What should I do for this MLP to work?

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer is to get `binary` representation of each `2^N` and train that with learning rate of 0.01 and Sigmoid activation function.

It is hard to generate exactly 2, 4, 8 in decimals, overflow might happen and your output will go `nan`. Instead generate binary representation of same length for all `y`s and train your network for that.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.power(2, x)
x = x.reshape((-1, 1))
lr = 0.01
o = list(map(lambda x:int(np.binary_repr(x)), y))
o = list(map(lambda x:"{:010d}".format(x), o))
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x], o)))
print(y, x)
```

Here's what you get.

```
(array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]))
```

It is our responsibility to not to let overflow happen. So activation function is necessary. You can come with your own intermediate representation within the scope of activation function.

Comment: yeah, nan is exactly what I'm getting after 10 or 11 training steps. I didn't understand what you mean by binary representation... you mean give as input for example `3` and as output `1 0 0 0` ? Seems a bit strange for me, as I just the net to create a parabola for `f(x) = 2^x`

Comment: in binary respresentation `f(x)` = `2^x`, `f(3)` = `2^3` = `8` = `1 0 0 0`.

Comment: in this case your have to specify bit length, 32, 64 etc. I gave max length of 10. you can train for f(x) which could be represented with number of bits you specify

Comment: I don't know if I get what you said, in a nutshell, are you suggesting that Is better to find a way to represent the outputs as value from 0 to 1? seem interesting if it's this (once my net already does that, it works with the XOR problem, etc)

Comment: yes. it may be 0 to 1(sigmoid) or  -1 to 1 (tanh) or any other which avoids overflow.

Comment: I'm still confused, does it make sense to have an output layer of 10 neurons that would store, for example the value of bits that represent the result of a function? aren't those bits too random to be trained? what would the input layer be?

Comment: obviously it can, once you get binay output , you can rectify it by another function making all values > 0.5 as 1 and lesser than that as 0, and convert binary representation to decimal representation once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161399/discussion-between-daniel-and-crook).